# Deployed small footprint tanzu application service(tas) in Azure,without no domains.Can i access the ccapi and apps manager with the IP?

Tags: azure, cloud-foundry

Could deploy Bosh and small footprint tanzu application service(tas) in Azure, without using the domains.All Vms are running.Can i access the ccapi and apps manager with the IP address instead of the api.SYSTEMDOMAIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. You really, really want to have DNS set up properly.

---

Here's the long answer that is more nuanced.

All requests to your foundation go through the Gorouter. Gorouter will take the incoming request, look at the `Host` header and use that to determine where to send the request. This happens the same for system services like CAPI and UAA as it does for apps you deploy to the foundation.

DNS is a requirement because of the `Host` header. A browser trying to access CAPI or an application on your foundation is going to set the `Host` header based on the DNS entry you type into your browser's address bar. The cf CLI is going to do the same thing.

There are some ways to work around this:

1. If you are strictly using a client like `curl` where you can set the `Host` header to arbitrary values. In that way, you could set the host header to `api.system_domain` and at the same time connect to the IP address of your foundation. That's not a very elegant way to use CF though.
2. You can manually set entries in your /etc/hosts` (or similar on Windows). This is basically a way to override DNS resolution and supply your own custom IP.

   You would need to do this for `uaa.system_domain`, `login.system_domain`, `api.system_domain` and any host names you want to use for apps deployed to your foundation, like `my-super-cool-app.apps_domain`. These should all point to the IP of the load balancer that's in front of your pool of Gorouters.

   If you add enough entries into `/etc/hosts` you can make the cf CLI work. I have done this on occasion to bypass the load balancer layer for troubleshooting purposes.

   Where this won't work is on systems where you can't edit `/etc/hosts`, like customers or external users of software running on your foundation or if you're trying to deploy apps on your foundation that talk to each other using routes on CF (because you can't edit `/etc/hosts` in the container). Like if you have `app-a.apps_domain` and `app-b.apps_domain` and `app-a` needs to talk to `app-b`. That won't work because you have no DNS resolution for `apps_domain`.

   You can probably make app-to-app communication work if you are able to use container-to-container networking and the `apps.internal` domain though. The resolution for that domain is provided by Bosh DNS. You have to be aware of this difference though when deploying your apps and map routes on the `apps.internal` domain, as well as setting network policy to allow traffic to flow between the two.

Anyway, there might be other hiccups. This is just off the top of my head. You can see it's a lot better if you can set up DNS.

Comment: Adding entries to hosts file worked for me. Thanks @daniel

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to achieve a portable solution is a service like [xip.io](http://xip.io/) that will work out of the box. I have setup and run a lot of PoCs that way, when wildcard DNS was something that enterprise IT was still oblivious about.

It works like this (excerpt from their site):

What is xip.io?
xip.io is a magic domain name that provides wildcard DNS
for any IP address. Say your LAN IP address is 10.0.0.1.
Using xip.io,

```
      10.0.0.1.xip.io   resolves to   10.0.0.1
  www.10.0.0.1.xip.io   resolves to   10.0.0.1
```

mysite.10.0.0.1.xip.io   resolves to   10.0.0.1
foo.bar.10.0.0.1.xip.io   resolves to   10.0.0.1

...and so on. You can use these domains to access virtual
hosts on your development web server from devices on your
local network, like iPads, iPhones, and other computers.
No configuration required!